# Where to get a reference of the OpenShift template "language"?

Tags: templates, openshift

I'm trying to learn how to write an OpenShift template. I found [the relevant section in the developer guide](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/templates.html#modifying-an-uploaded-template). Which commes with some examples.

But I cannot find any defintions about the template file contents, except that it's a yaml or json file.

I know how to extract template files from the openshift server, which is a good starting point. What I'm missing is a description of *all* possible configuration parameters.

Comment: The "Writing Templates" section of that page you link does a pretty good job of explaining what you can add in them. What exactly do you feel is missing or what don't you understand?

Comment: It does describe some details about templates. But I need details about how to define a DeploymentConfig, Service, Route, etc.

Comment: They have nothing specific to do with templates. How to define those is a separate concern as you can create those resources independent of templates. A template is just a way of parameterising values in them. If you want absolute lowest level details in the way of schema, see for example https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/oapi/v1.DeploymentConfig.html#Post-oapi-v1-deploymentconfigs but you probably don't. See instead https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/deployments/how_deployments_work.html Lots of details in developers guide.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton First link is broken. Given how it supposedly includes version number (`3.11`), I am a bit perplexed as to why it's a HTTP 404 there -- has the link ever worked, and shouldn't it then be HTTP "410 Gone" instead, anyway?

Comment: I'm really intrigued as to what the process is for how folks get things done in openshift yaml. 

For example, I am working on an openshift template with the 'id' parameter in a 'route' object. I cannot find any docs around parameter in the https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/networking/routes/route-configuration.html docs, but I can't tell if this is because it is not supported and being ignored, or just not documented. 

It always seems to be like this for everything I try to understand and there is no simple list of 'here are all the allowed options for each object type.